# CMake для компиляции многопоточного приложения в линукс g++

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность, cmake

Как я понял для компиляции многопоточного приложения с помощью g++ стоит добавить флаг -lpthread когда программа собирается из уже скомпилированный объектных файлов (*.o). т.е. к примеру для компиляции данного кода (пример из интернета)

```
  #include <future>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <thread>

  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
      int count = 10;

    auto yn = 'y';
    std::cout << "is async y/n : ";
    std::cin >> yn;

    auto f1 = [&count] {
        for(int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << "| 1 |\n";
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        }
    };

    auto f2 = [&count] {
        for(int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << "| 2 |\n";
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        }
    };

    if(yn == 'y')
    {
        auto future1 = std::async(std::launch::async, f1);
        auto future2 = std::async(std::launch::async, f2);
    }
    else
    {
        std::async(std::launch::async, f1);
        std::async(std::launch::async, f2);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

нужно указывать следующие флаги:

```
g++ -Wall -c main.cpp -o  main.o
g++ -o main_program main.o -lpthread
```

Так как я сейчас разбираюсь с тем как создавать CMake файлы, то решил скомпилировать все через CMake. написал следующий файл:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project(test_threads_std_async)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1y -Wall -lpthread")

set(SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
```

Однако он не компилирует программу, как полагается. Как верно прописать CMake файл ?

Comment: @vegorov из пары примеров в сети

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` задает флаги компилятора, за компоновку библиотек отвечает линкер,

Только в самых простых программах с парой исходников компиляция и компоновка происходит в один этап.

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread)
```

Comment: В более сложных приложениях, так же указывается линковка библиотек, или же будут свои нюансы ?

Comment: В любых приложениях, в которых используется cmake, библиотеки нужно указывать в target_link_libraries. Обычно только при компиляции "на коленке" или с минималистичным Makefile, написанным вручную, пропускают этап создания объектных файлов.

Comment: Я вроде делал через find_package(Threads REQUIRED), а потом target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}   Threads::Threads).